# Esta función me sigue dando none y no se porque

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quería pedir ayuda con esta función (cryptsolver). Esta función recibe inputs del usuario y segun el input, esta debería entrar a alguno de los ifs o elifs the abajo. El problema es que no importa que letra yo ponga en el programa, siempre me tira `None`.

Este es el código:

```
 def cryptsolver():

  msg = raw_input("Escribe aqui el mesaje a encriptar ")
  encript = raw_input("Prefieres encritar con Hat kid(H) o con Pikachu(P)?. si quieres desencriptar presiona D, si quieres terminar el programa presiona S ")

  print encript
  print type(encript)
  encript = encript

  if encript == "H" or encript == "h":

    llave = input("introduce aquí la clave numerica ")

    msg_enc = encHatkid(msg, llave)

    return msg_enc

  elif encript == "P":

    llave = raw_input("introduce aquí la palabra clave ")

    msg_enc = encPikachu(msg, llave)

    return msg_enc

  elif encript == "D":

    encript2 = raw_input("Quieres desencriptar HatKid(H) o Pikachu(P)? ")

    if encript2 == "H": 

      llave = input("introduce aqui la llave numerica ")

      msg_dec = desHatkid(msg, llave)

      return msg_dec

    elif encript2 == "P":

      llave = raw_input("introduce aqui la palabra clave")

      msg_dec = desPikachu(msg, llave)

      return msg_dec

    else:
       return cryptsolver()
```

PD: estoy ocupando python 2.7

Edit: Aqui esta el link del codigo completo https://repl.it/@JoseSantiagoSan/AmazingTallProgrammers

Comment: Hola. Es difícil de decir sin saber que hay dentro de las funciones `encHatkid`,  `encHatkid`, etc. ¿Son una librería externa?

Comment: Amigo, te dejo este [link](https://repl.it/languages/python) para que lo puedas compartir con tus archivos correspondientes junto a la pregunta y así poder ayudarte

Comment: César , no son funciones que codifique yo, Harifo, no sabia que se podían compartir links por repl.it, gracias por la info. PD:aqui esta el link https://repl.it/@JoseSantiagoSan/AmazingTallProgrammers

Comment: Amigo, en el link que compartiste tu programa funciona perfectamente, me atrevería a decir que no tiene el error mencionado, revisalo y si lo estimas, cierra la pregunta. Si aún sigue, te recomendaría revisar las librerías que utilizas para encriptar.

Comment: Es cierto, no me funciona en mi ambiente instalado en mi pc pero si en repl.it :(, alguna idea de porque podría ser?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo ejecutas en tu ambiente? ¿Linea de comandos desde una terminal? ¿Algún tipo de IDE?

Comment: @abulafia ocupo un IDE, específicamente Visual Studio Code, tengo python 2.7 y 3.7 instalado si sirve de algo.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo ejecutas dentro de ese IDE? ¿Por dónde te pide el input? Prueba a abrir una terminal (aunque sea dentro del propio IDE) y ejecutarlo directamente con python a ver.

Comment: @abulafia a que te refieres con por donde me pide el input? Empece a programar hace unos 3 meses por lo que soy bastante nuevo :(. Si te refieres a como ejecuto el programa lo debuggeo con el botón que ya trae instalado el IDE.

Comment: Solo cambia los `raw_input()` por `input()`. Solo manejas string ingresados por el usuarios, no son **pythoneables**.